# Access current running script error log

Tags: php, javascript

Is it possible to capture all of the PHP errors that occur during a site execution, save them to a variable and print them out into a javascript section to print?

i.e.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what `set_error_handler` is for  .. see  for a working example and full documentation

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

You should also look at `set_exception_handler`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php

Example

```
set_error_handler('my_error_handler');
set_exception_handler('my_exception_handler');

function my_exception_handler($e) {
    exit('Huston! We have a problem: '.$e);
}

function my_error_handler($no,$str,$file,$line) {
    $e = new ErrorException($str,$no,0,$file,$line);
    my_exception_handler($e);     /* Do not throw, simply call error handler with exception object */
}
```